# How to reduce the disk size of your Angular project?

Tags: angular

I created a new Angular project using ng new ProjectName command. Then I found that the size of the node_modules folder in my project happens to be 290MB. This is strange, why should I lose so much disk space for each and every project I create. Any idea how to reduce this size?

Comment: You could consider a monorepo, where all your projects share a package file.

Comment: Welcome to the world of web development. Every now and again it is a good idea to remove node module folders from old/stale projects.

Answer (score 2):

Use [pnpm](https://pnpm.io/) or [yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/) instead of **npm**. If you just want less disk space, **pnpm** is the closest to **npm** in terms of usage, while keeping it simple.

Unlike **npm**, the above package managers allow for the use of a single global store for all projects, which can significantly reduce the disk space required for storing dependencies.

They make it so dependencies of the same version that you use more than once will be cached and retrieved without the need to make an individual install for each project that needs them, on your local machine.

Additionally, if you're concerned about project size due to version control, it is good to know that the `node_modules` folder should be **ignored** when committing to a repository.